# Parsing XML with PowerShell: Getting the value of an element with an attribute

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have an XML file which has elements with attributes.  I want to be able to read both the attribute value and the element value.  While I can get the attribute value, when I try to read the element value it just returns the tag name, not the value.

XML file C:\Temp\books2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date inprint="false">2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date inprint="true">2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk103">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date inprint="false">2000-11-17</publish_date>
      <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
      society in England, the young survivors lay the 
      foundation for a new society.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

What I've tried:

```
$xmlDoc = new-object -TypeName xml
$filePath = "C:\Temp\Books2.xml"
$xmlDoc.Load($filePath)
$xmlDoc.catalog.book | select author, title, publish_date, `
    {$_.publish_date}, {$_.publish_date.inprint}
```

Result:

```
author                  : Gambardella, Matthew
title                   : XML Developer's Guide
publish_date            : publish_date
$_.publish_date         : publish_date
$_.publish_date.inprint : false

author                  : Ralls, Kim
title                   : Midnight Rain
publish_date            : publish_date
$_.publish_date         : publish_date
$_.publish_date.inprint : true

author                  : Corets, Eva
title                   : Maeve Ascendant
publish_date            : publish_date
$_.publish_date         : publish_date
$_.publish_date.inprint : false
```

How can I read the value of the element that also contains an attribute (in this case publish_date)?  I want to read the date value for the publish_date, not the tag name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access the text content of the `publish_date` XML element.
To do this, use the following syntax:

```
$xmlDoc.catalog.book | select author, title, publish_date, `
    {$_.publish_date.'#text'}, {$_.publish_date.inprint}
```

Comment: Thanks Christophe.  Do you know where these details might be documented?  I've found lots of blog posts about parsing simple XML documents but they're all sample code, they don't give explanations and don't go into it in much depth.

Comment: You're welcome. If you want specific information about the XML tehnology you can check this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms256177%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. You can also check the MSXML documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms256177%28v=vs.110%29.aspx since you use MSXML objects to access XML data.

Comment: Also you can check XPath, it's a quick and easy way to get XML data: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms256086%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I checked the data type of the objects returned by PowerShell: `($xmlDoc.catalog).gettype().fullname` .  It turns out the objects representing the nodes have data type System.Xml.XmlElement.  So I tried using the XmlElement.InnerText property, and that worked:

```
$xmlDoc.catalog.book | select author, title, publish_date, `
{$_.publish_date.innertext}, {$_.publish_date.inprint} | format-list
```

Result:

```
author                    : Gambardella, Matthew
title                     : XML Developer's Guide
publish_date              : publish_date
$_.publish_date.innertext : 2000-10-01
$_.publish_date.inprint   : false

author                    : Ralls, Kim
title                     : Midnight Rain
publish_date              : publish_date
$_.publish_date.innertext : 2000-12-16
$_.publish_date.inprint   : true

author                    : Corets, Eva
title                     : Maeve Ascendant
publish_date              : publish_date
$_.publish_date.innertext : 2000-11-17
$_.publish_date.inprint   : false
```